# IntelliJ: Live Edit doesn't work with node.js

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I tried to use Live Edit with node.js. I followed the instructions here:

> To enable Live Edit in a Node.js application Install the LiveEdit
>   plugin on the Plugins settings page as described in Managing Plugins.
>
> In the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), click Debugger under
>   Build, Execution, Deployment, and then click Live Edit. The Live Edit
>   page opens.
>
> Select Update Node.js application on changes. Specify the time-delay
>   between changing the code in the editor and showing this change in the
>   browser: accept the default value 300 ms or specify a custom value
>   using the spin box next to the corresponding field.

Here is the link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-and-debugging-node-js.html?fbclid=IwAR1LH-LY86RDNDmqELfh_KcnZI9N-CqQj6vT935soycGYXGkEEcat5S2X6g

Unfortunately, it didn't work out. 
I changed the code during its run, and the behavior didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Hot-swapping works, but it changes the code and not application state... Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29792#focus=streamItem-27-2906077-0-0

If you need server to be restarted, using nodemon is the right way to go. Suggested run configuration that works ok to me (no exits on restart):

```
Node interpreter: <the path to node>
Node parameters: <empty>
Working directory: <project directory>
JavaScript file: node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js
Application parameters: path/to/your/main.js
```